# Kernel Panic due to bad paging request

Tags: linux, crash, linux-kernel, paging

What can be the reasons for the kernel to panic due to

```
 Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 0x00000024 epc=0x9caf9876 ra=0x9432adfc
```

1. Address not yet dynamically allocated
2. No corresponding virtual address entry in page table

What else?

Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: Hardware (RAM, CPU, motherboard) fault, buggy driver, buggy modules, too hot or insufficiently cooled or overclocked machine... For instance, a bad RAM and overheated chipset did gave me similar issues (6 years ago). Changing RAM solved that issue.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Hardware RAM error in the sense, that particular physical address that was mapped for the virtual address will never be useful?

Comment: do dmesg ... after the crash u ll probably get the source of error

Answer (score 1):

> virtual address 0x00000024

Surely that's a NULL pointer dereference?  Accessing `p->field`, where `p == NULL` and `offsetof(typeof(p), field) == 0x24`.

EDIT: ah, note this doesn't explain a full panic.  Most frequently, a NULL pointer dereference would take down one task, log "OOPS" and a bracktrace, and let you try to shut down.  With a panic, all you could do is hit the hard reboot button.

If you had a NULL-pointer dereference inside the MM, maybe that would be a reason for a full panic.  I think the surrounding messages would let you determine whether that was the case.